# Azure Table Storage inserting date properties incorrectly

Tags: c#, datetime, azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

**Why do I have to create my entities' `DateTime` properties with `DateTimeKind.Local`?**

For example, I need to set the following property like so before inserting it into my table:

```
someObject.DatePerformed = new DateTime(2012, 11, 19, 3, 3, 3, DateTimeKind.Local);
```

If I do not specify `DateTimeKind` then it is saved incorrectly (2 hours are added).  This happens on both my local storage emulator and on my Azure account. I am running the client application from my local machine at GMT +2 hours.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not an Azure issue, this is how DateTime works.  You need to specify the time zone for the object `DateTime`.

To avoid issues when users are in different time zones, I recommend storing everything in UTC and then resolving it to local time at runtime.

Otherwise you are heading down a path of issues when manually converting timezones.

Answer (score 4):

Azure runs on UTC time.  If you are using DateTime.Now, use DateTime.AddHours().

```
var utcOffset = 2;
var dateValue = new DateTime(2009, 3, 1, 12, 0, 0);
var localTime = dateValue.AddHours(utcOffset);
```

or...

```
var localValue = DateTime.Now.AddHours(utcOffset);
```

Comment: due to day light savings times (in the US), this is not a sufficient solution.